# Add connection to DBAL dynamically in Silex

Tags: php, doctrine, silex, dbal

I am writing a PHP application using the Silex framework. I'm using the Doctrine Service Provider, and I can open a connection normally as this:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider(), array(
    'dbs.options' => array (
        'localhost' => array(
            'driver'    => 'pdo_mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'dbname'    => 'test',
            'user'      => 'root',
            'password'  => 'root',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
        )
    ),
));
```

That works perfectly. What I want now is to add another database connection afterwards in my code. I know I can do it adding another element to dbs.options, but I want to do it afterwards, in the controllers (as different controllers will use different database connections).

Is that possible? I guess I could use something like `DriverManager::getConnection($options, $config, $manager);` but there's probably a better way to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$conn = DriverManager::getConnection($params, $config);
```

this is original code to generate new connection, so what you wrote is ok

Link: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html

Answer (score 2):

You can configure multiple db connections using the `DoctrineServiceProvider` bundled with Silex.

Replace the `db.options` with an array of configurations where keys are connection names and values configuration options.

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider(), array(
    'dbs.options' => array (
        'mysql_read' => array(
            'driver'    => 'pdo_mysql',
            'host'      => 'mysql_read.someplace.tld',
            'dbname'    => 'my_database',
            'user'      => 'my_username',
            'password'  => 'my_password',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
        ),
        'mysql_write' => array(
            'driver'    => 'pdo_mysql',
            'host'      => 'mysql_write.someplace.tld',
            'dbname'    => 'my_database',
            'user'      => 'my_username',
            'password'  => 'my_password',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
        ),
    ),
));
```

Access multiple connections in your controllers:

```
$app->get('/blog/{id}', function ($id) use ($app) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = ?";
    $post = $app['dbs']['mysql_read']->fetchAssoc($sql, array((int) $id));

    $sql = "UPDATE posts SET value = ? WHERE id = ?";
    $app['dbs']['mysql_write']->executeUpdate($sql, array('newValue', (int) $id));

    return  "<h1>{$post['title']}</h1>".
            "<p>{$post['body']}</p>";
});
```

Source: http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/doctrine.html

Comment: This is not what was being asked.